# Coldfusion loop query results and update using dynamic column names

Tags: coldfusion, cfloop

In the database I have 5 columns plus the id:

```
 id, m1, m2, m3, m4, m5
```

I'm selecting from one table that may have from 1 to 5 rows based on the id:

```
row,id,value
 1, 1, 'A'
 2, 1, 'B'
 3, 1, 'C'
```

etc
What I need to do is update columns m1, m2 and m3 in the user table for user ID 1 with values A, B and C.  I've started down the path of something like this but am hitting serious Monday brain on a Tuesday.

```
i=1;
  cfloop (query=q) {
    field = 'm' & i;
    temp = invoke(myCFC,"updateUser",{ userid=q.id, field = q.value });
    i++;
  };
```

Where 'field' would be m1, m2, m3.  One way would be to use a switch/case on the recordcount and have 5 different invokes, but not sure if there would be a better way programatically?

[edit] this works but may not be the best way - I have cases for 1-5:

```
switch(qryM.recordCount) {
case "1":
    temp = invoke(userCFC,"updateUser", { 
        id = qryM.rsm_userid, 
        m1_c = qryM["rsm_c"][1], 
        m1_m = qryM["rsm_m"][1]
    });
    break;
case "2":
    temp = invoke(userCFC,"updateUser", { 
        id = qryM.rsm_userid, 
        m1_c = qryM["rsm_c"][1], 
        m1_m = qryM["rsm_m"][1],
        m2_c = qryM["rsm_c"][2], 
        m2_m = qryM["rsm_m"][2]
    });     
    break;
```

Comment: What's `cfloop`? This syntax is unfamiliar to me. Would it not be a `for` loop in CFScript, and if it's not CFScript, then a `<cfloop>` tag?

Comment: I was using for / in loops but saw a blog post that cfloop(query=, group=) etc. works.  I'd never seen it before today.  Running CF2016 update 7.

Comment: You're right, this works. I completely missed that, I'm going to have tot do some reading.

Comment: cfloop() will work in cfscript. Almost all tags will work like that in cfscript. It is useful for making stuff pure cfscript, but it can lead to strangeness. In this case, I would go for a for-in solution.

Comment: Are you updating all 5 columns, or just one of them? If you loop through your query2 to do a query1.column update for each row, you'll be beating up on your database. You may be able to do what you want with a PIVOT. Do you have sample data? And some expectations?

Comment: And do you need to fall back to CF to do this? You can do this in pure SQL. What is your workflow for this?

Comment: And you definitely wouldn't want to `invoke` for every iteration. You could `new` or `createobject` before your loop and then just call your method on each iteration.

Comment: And are you `INSERT`ing, `UPDATE`ing or both? And this is for a single `id`, correct? You won't have multiple `id`s? And if `UPDATE`ing, if your database already has `m4`, but you only have 3 rows, will you `null` out `m4` and `UPDATE` 1-3, or will you leave `m4` as-is?

Answer (score 0):

If there really can only ever be a maximum of five rows and the target column always is "m" + the current row number, then this would work:

```
for (row in q) {
    myCFC.updateUser(userid:row.id, field:'m#q.CurrentRow#');
}
```

Comment: the columns would be m1, m2, m3, m4, m5 and the values would be qryM["rsc_m"][currentrow] - I kept getting errors though on the dynamic field names part.  What would happen if I defined all 5 field names but only had values for the first 3 rows?  Does qryM[rsc_m][5] throw an error if the query record count is 3 and I try to put in a value for row 4 or 5?

Comment: Well, with a `for ... in` loop you don't need to use the `[CurrentRow]` reference. When there are only 3 rows then the query runs only 3 times, and yes there would be an error when you try to access row 4. Still not quite sure what the issue is, I admit.